# Iframe preventing rest of page from loading?

Tags: html, iframe, load

I have an iframe loaded within a page. This code works fine in firefox but not in ie - it does not load anything following the iframe. If i move the iframe to the bottom of the page everything loads correctly. Has anyone encountered this error before?

```
head----
<style> 
iframe{    
margin-left: 22px;
height: 112px;
width: 612px;
}  
body{background-color:transparent}    
</style> 

body---
<img align="left" border="0" src="http://picurl.com"/><br />
<p>text</p>
<iframe frameborder="0" src='http://URL.com'</iframe><br />
<p>big load of text</p>
```

Text loads fine, content of iframe loads correctly but 'big load of text' does not. Why does this happen? I am using internet explorer 8 for this task, can't change this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed a `>` from the end of your iframe tag:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src='http://URL.com'></iframe>
```

Comment: @idb - Which version of FF? BTW, since you have a solution you should accept one of the answers.